# ¿Porqué XXX no se reconoce como comando externo o interno?

Tags: windows, cmd

Al tratar de abrir XXX en consola me da el error

> no se reconoce "XXX" como comando externo o interno

pero si arrastro XXX a la consola puedo correrlo sin problemas.

Para este caso XXX puede ser cualquier programa .exe o .bat

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que XXX no está en tu PATH, o mejor dicho, como no está referenciado en tu variable de sistema  PATH, la línea de comandos no lo encuentra.

Desde cmd puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path\here\XXX
```

Alternativamente puedes crear una nueva variable de sistema y agregarla a tu PATH

```
set MY_VARIABLE=C:\your\path\here\XXX
set PATH=%PATH%;%MY_VARIABLE%
```

o incluso referenciar la carpeta que contiene tu programa en una variable de sistema

```
set MY_VARIABLE=C:\your\path\here
set PATH=%PATH%;%MY_VARIABLE%/XXX
```

una vez que agregas una variable de sistema debes de cerrar tu terminal pues estos valores se cargan cada vez que se abre